# Remotely fatch content for Panel in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I am implementing bootstrap panel in one my webpages in project let say - `index.html`. Now, What I need to do is, when click on Header of panel it will open accordion with data, but this data should come from other page let call it - `accordData.html`

I search on it, but mostly get suggestion on remote data fetch for modal.

How can I fetch data in panel from other page when click on accordion?

Comment: use events triggered by accordion to make ajax call

Comment: @charlietfl: thank you, but if you provide with example than it will really help me.

Comment: `$('#myAccordion').load('accord.html')` ... http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("#foo").click(function(){
     $.ajax({
       method: "GET",
       url: "some.php",
       success: function (data)
      {
           $("#bar").html(data);
      }
       });
})
```

Assuming you return a formatted HTML string.